# Bootstrapping RequireJS app with jQuery as a module without data-main attribute

Tags: jquery, requirejs, javascript

In the app working with, I don't have a way of specyfing attributes on the  tag for requirejs. I can specify the script tag in the form of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

I can append another tag before or after this one and include code to bootstrap my app (main module). I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and would like to load it as dependency in other modules. I also want to do that without the requirejs-jquery bundle, so jQuery seperate of requirejs.
I am looking for the right way to do that. I am fairly new to requirejs so an explanation of how the modules are loaded and a code sample would be great. Thanks!

Comment: have you read the jquery tutorial on require.js's documentation?  It's very helpful - http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: I have. The examples there do use the data-main attribute and that is where I am getting a little lost. I am hoping that someone has figured out THE right way to do this 'alternative configuration' and is willing to share here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

include another javascript file **after** requirejs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/main.js"></script>
```

In this file you have to configure requirejs so it finds jquery.

**`main.js`**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "js/jquery-1.7.1.min"//edit this path so it suits your needs.
  } 
});
```

From now on you'll be able to load jquery into your Modules by

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $('#foo').show();
});
```

Comment: Could you explain where that last require belongs? Is that in main.js or another module? If latter, how do you tell it to load that in main.js?

Comment: After requirejs is loaded, you can use `require()` wherever you want to.
This can be the main.js or any other js you load.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up renaming main.js to requirejs-config.js with require(["main"]) call at the end. That way requirejs-config.js configures the paths and tells requirejs which file to load first. The main file then has no bootstrapping/configuration logic.

Comment: This does open up the possibility of errors - main.js depends on require.js and occasionally you may find that main.js is loaded before require.js which results in a define is not defined error.

Comment: Loading scripts is synchronous. If you don't add a async attribute to the script element loading requirejs, it will be there.