# Should RequireJS take care of all the external JavaScript libraries in my App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am using RequireJS (and learning it) and I do not understand whether or not RequireJS should manage the external libraries in my application. At the moment I have a script tag for jQuery, another for jQuery Tools and so on. I also successfully added RequireJS to my app and I wonder if the only script tag that should be in the HTML is that from RequireJS?

If so, will jQuery etc be added correctly on pages even though I don't use it as a dependency in a module?

Answer (score 2):

You could always add jquery as a dependency to your main file, the file linked to via the requirejs script tag's data-main.  That solves everything here I believe.

[This post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330903/bootstrapping-requirejs-app-with-jquery-as-a-module-without-data-main-attribute?rq=1) pretty well details what you'd want to do.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder if the only script tag that should be in the HTML is that from RequireJS?

There isn't a "right" answer to that. Both approaches have their merits.

> If so, will jQuery etc be added correctly on pages even though I don't use it as a dependency in a module?

No. Require has no way to know it has to load jQuery unless you tell it to. The documentation [has an entire page](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) on the subject.

Comment: Okey so including those first with script tags is the only way if the jQuery plugins etc automatically bind to elements with a partiuclar class etc?